# I want to make an iframe hidden by default and to be shown onclick (of an image).

Tags: html, iframe

But with what I have done, if I make the display mode : none or block then I cant make it shown on click.

Also when I click on the show/hide image it scrolls at the beginning of the page, instead of staying at the same place and showing the iframe.

Any help for that?

With that below I made the show/hide function

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>

    $(document).ready(function(){

      $("#on").click(function(){

        $("map").show();

      });

      $("#off").click(function(){

        $("map").show(); 

      });

    });

    </script>
```

I frame and image are:

```
<div id="show/hide" align="center">
    <a href="#" id="on">
      <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/double-j-design/apple-festival/256/app-map-icon.png"  width="80" height="80">
    </a>
```

```
<div id="map" style="display:block ;"> 
  <iframe src="https://mapsengine.google.com/map/embed?mid=zkhFhUgoi5X4.kL86cmKz_OL8" height="300px" width=" 100%" ></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/Z62P7/1/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your page is scrolling because `display:none` actually "deletes" the iframe from the DOM, which using a CSS style of `visibility: hidden;` would leave the iframe in place, but just hide it.

If that's what you would like to do then use the following (notice the `visibility:hidden` style):

**HTML**

```
<div id="map" style="display:block; visibility:hidden"> 
  <iframe src="https://mapsengine.google.com/map/embed?mid=zkhFhUgoi5X4.kL86cmKz_OL8" height="300px" width=" 100%" ></iframe>
</div>
```

You can choose to use `display: block`, or any other display style you want -- just ***DO NOT*** use `display: none`, as it will act as if it ***REMOVES*** the object from the DOM.

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#on").click(function(){
    if ( $("map").css('visibility') = 'hidden') {
      $("map").css('visibility') = 'visible';
    }
    else {
      $("map").css('visibility') = 'hidden';
    }
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you call `preventDefault();` on a clicked `a` tag, you can cancel the "scroll event". Implementation can look something like this. [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8367x/).

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#button').click(function (e) {
        $('.map').fadeToggle();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will fork for you if you place the # in front of the id in your jquery command:

$("#map").show() and $("#map").hide()

Also, you have called .show() on both functions. I would assume on your second you would like to call .hide()